# How to know that a class can be encoded to Circe Json

Tags: scala, circe

Let's say I have a method that takes as an argument a class that is generic. What does that generic have to implement to be encodable with Circe? ie How can we know that this class has an encoder defined?

```
def func[C: TraitIWouldLikeToKnowAbout](jsonEncodable: C) = ???
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to let the compiler know that `C` should have an implicit `Encoder` instance in scope:

```
def func[C <: TraitIWouldLikeToKnowAbout : Encoder](jsonEncodable: C) = ???
```

which is a shorthand for the implicit evidence parameter of type `Encoder[C]`

```
def func[C <: TraitIWouldLikeToKnowAbout](jsonEncodable: C)(implicit en: Encoder[C]) = ???
```

And then obviously you need to make sure that instance of `Encoder[C]` is available in scope, either via (semi-)automatic derivation or manually declared.